# Append to system variable path from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, system-variable

I want to add a few lines to Windows system variable path.

The batch file I have now appends these lines to user variable, not system variable.

How do I need to change it in order to append to system variable?

Here's my batch command:

`SETX path "%PATH%;C:\development\sdk\tools;C:\development\sdk\platform-tools"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setx /M` to modify the system var (**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**), by default it modifies the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER**